# How to make perfect text alignment with Sans-serif fonts?

Tags: html, css

I am working on this page:
[image]

As you can see, "BE" slightly does not align with "WITH" on the left (It is more noticeable on wider screens).  There is no padding or margins on `headline`, `head1` or `head2`. And everything in a span is `text-align:left`. I am using fittext.js, but I even tried using a whole number as the font size. The font is just a basic: `font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

Code involved:

```
<div class="headline">
    <span class="head1" style="font-size: 84.7058823529412px;">be important</span>
    <span class="head2" style="font-size: 28.8px;">with a 1:19 professor to student ratio</span>
</div>
```

CSS involved

```
.slide .headline {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
.important_slide .headline span {
  text-align: left;
}
.slide .headline span {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
.important_slide .headline .head2 {
  margin-top: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Nice picture. Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Please also show css for head1 and head2 and headline.

Comment: Usually that's just the way the font glyph is...it includes space.

Comment: I figured everything that you needed to know was in the screenshot and my description. I have updated the post to include code.

Comment: In your screenshot, it looks like the `headline` class has a `::before` rule applied to it. If so, why is this not included in the CSS you pasted above?

Comment: The ::before rule is applied to the parent div of headline. That's why it's not included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing an artifact of how the font is designed.

For example, if you use a serif font, the top-left serif on the "b" lines up with the left edge of the `span`, and so does the left edge of the "w".

However, if you use a sans-serif font, the "b" has no serif and appears slightly off from the left edge of the `span`.

There is no work around for this except to pick a font family that has all the characters aligned to the left edge of the glyph box.

```css
span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
.ex1 {
    font-family: serif;
}
.ex2 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
b {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: monospace;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline ex1">
  <b>Ex1:</b>
    <span class="head1" style="font-size: 84.7058823529412px;">be important</span>
    <span class="head2" style="font-size: 28.8px;">with a 1:19 professor to student ratio</span>
</div>
<div class="headline ex2">
  <b>Ex2:</b>
    <span class="head1" style="font-size: 84.7058823529412px;">be important</span>
    <span class="head2" style="font-size: 28.8px;">with a 1:19 professor to student ratio</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'll find a new font.

Answer (score 0):

Add a break tag after the first span.

```
<div class="headline">
<span class="head1" style="font-size: 84.7058823529412px;">be important</span><br />
<span class="head2" style="font-size: 28.8px;">with a 1:19 professor to student ratio</span>
```